# How to generalize scala type that works in Array

Tags: scala, types

I have below code:

```
trait Vehicle {
  def regNumber: String
  def lotSize: Int
}
case class Car(regNumber: String) extends Vehicle {override val lotSize = 2}
case class Motorcycle(regNumber: String) extends Vehicle {override val lotSize = 1}

trait AbstractLot[+T <: Vehicle] {
  def vehicle: T
  def lotSize: Int = vehicle.lotSize
}
final case class CarLot(vehicle: Car) extends AbstractLot[Car]
final case class MotorcycleLot(vehicle: Motorcycle) extends AbstractLot[Motorcycle]
```

I want to have a `ParkingLot` type which is an array of option of abstract lot. But, Scala compiler is not happy when I wrote below code

```
object ParkingLot {
  type ParkingLot = Array[Option[AbstractLot[_]]]

  //Case 1: OK
  def mixMotorcycleCar(motorcycleCapacity: Int, carCapacity: Int): ParkingLot =
    Array.fill[Option[MotorcycleLot]](motorcycleCapacity)(None) +: Array.fill[Option[CarLot]](carCapacity)(None)

  //Case 2: Not OK
  //T is a subclass of AbstractLot. Why isn't this working?
  def homogenous[T <: AbstractLot[_]](capacity: Int): ParkingLot = Array.fill[Option[T]](capacity)(None)

  //Case 3: Not OK
  def carOnly(capacity: Int): ParkingLot = Array.fill[Option[CarLot]](capacity)(None)

}
```

What did I do wrong? And how should I fix my code so that I can have a `ParkingLot` type that works in Case 2 and Case 3?

Comment: How do you expect to use each lot if you do not know if it is a motorcycle loc or a vehicle loc? You need to redesign this, either using an **ADT** _(I would recommend this)_ or a type member instead of a type parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm sure the design could be better. But, I'm not sure if I follow your explanation. In Case 1, it is ok to have an array of a mix of MotorLot and CarLot referenced by AbstractLot. But why can't I have an array CarLot (only) referenced by AbstractLot as in Case 2 and Case 3?

Comment: As @Ava explained due invariance, which in turn is due mutability. Those two are reasons why you shouldn't be using plain **Arrays** in Scala unless you really need them for performance. I would suggest using a **List** or **Vector** or an **ArraySeq** and making sure your solution is immutable, use things like `map` to create modified copies.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and suggestions. It helps my understanding a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that mutable collections have invariant element types in Scala so you can't store `Option[CarLot]` nor `Option[MotorcycleLot]` elements in `Array[Option[AbstractLot[Any]]]`. The reason for this can be found here: [relation between variance and mutabilty / immutability in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18560418/relation-between-variance-and-mutabilty-immutability-in-scala).

ParkingLot object is used mainly for space preallocation which is rarely needed in Scala. You have to rethink your design because it won't be possible to create any mutable collection with covariant type. The simplest way to represent a parking lot using a mutable collection would be something like this:

```
val parkingLot = ArrayBuffer[Vehicle]()
parkingLot.addOne(Car("123"))
parkingLot.addOne(Motorcycle("321"))
```